# Aviary Feather Editor 3. Launching with a new image

Tags: javascript, image, editing, aviary

Im trying to relaunch the feather editor with a new image.

So the code below loads fine the first time the editor is opened and launchStatus is equal to true

var launchStatus =  self.featherEditor.launch({
           image: 'image_to_edit_aviary',
           url :image_1.jpg,
           noCloseButton: true,
           hideWaitIndicator : true
});

Now if i change the url of the image and relaunch the editor launchStatus is now false and the editor doesn't load. but if i try launching a second time with the new image it loads fine. Anyone experience anything similar?

var launchStatus =  self.featherEditor.launch({
           image: 'image_to_edit_aviary',
           url :image_2.jpg,
           noCloseButton: true,
           hideWaitIndicator : true
});

Comment: I can't tell without more code, but it when you say "launching a second time...loads fine" makes me think you may have discovered the race condition that's described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222589/script-loaded-with-headjs-runs-only-on-second-click