# Script loaded with HeadJS runs only on second click

Tags: javascript, aviary

Script loaded with HeadJS runs only on second click. How to get Aviary launcher on first click?

http://jsfiddle.net/ynts/6hgEb/

```
function aviary(id, src) {
    var $id = id;
    var $src = src;

    head.load(
        "http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js",
        function() {

            var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
                apiKey: 12345,
                apiVersion: 3

                // ... ///
            });

            featherEditor.launch({
                image: $id,


                  url: $src
                });
            }
        ); 
}

$(document).on('click', 'img', function(){
    var $img = $(this).attr('src');
    aviary('edit-pic', $img);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait for the plugin to initialize, before calling the `launch` function. There is `onLoad` event you can use:

```
var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
                apiKey: 12345,
                apiVersion: 3,
                onLoad: function() {
                     featherEditor.launch({
                        image: $id,
                        url: $src
                    });
                }                                    
            });
```

Comment: onLoad isn't firing for me the second time I instantiate  Aviary.Feather: http://jsfiddle.net/gvom5tu7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Answering mikebridge, for the case when it doesn`t open a second time:

Some dark reason prevents feather to be instantiated more than once.
Use window.globalAviaryFeather to hold the instance.

```
function launch(url) {
    window.globalAviaryFeather.launch({
        image: "imgId",
        url: url
    })
}

var url = "..."

if (window.globalAviaryFeather) {
    launch(url)

} else {
    window.globalAviaryFeather = new Aviary.Feather({
        ...
        onLoad: function() {
            self.launch(url)
        }
    })
}
```